# Excel-Dna get globals properties

Tags: excel, com, vsto, excel-dna

I am using excel-dna as base function, then I call a "vsto" function from an addin to trigger a web service request on the selected function. My issue is that I d like to use the DNA function to parse the ranges to be send to the service. It return a string currently ("waiting for service call..."), and if the VSTO methods call the function it passed another variable to return something else.

I cannot extract other thing than string, object comes back empty when I use "evaluate" in vsto.

I think the best way would be to reach a global cache variable stored in the vsto addin from the excel-dna function. I could not manage to to this.

Addins button push => addins evaluate Excel DNA => DNA store data in VSTO Addin variable => VSTO call the service and paste the returning data.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out on:
[MSN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationserv%E2%97%98ice/)

```
namespace AddIn{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("****************************")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IAddinUtilities
    { void youraddinfunction();
    }

  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public partial class ThisAddIn : IAddinUtilities
    {
        protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        { return this; }

        public void yourfunction (){ DoSomething }   
}
```

In the excel Dna function :

```
var application = (Application)XL.ExcelDnaUtil.Application;

            var addin = application.COMAddIns.Item(AddinName);
            var what = addin.Object;
            what.youraddinfunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoyo's approach is strictly speaking correct, but for an approach that is more portable, I suggest combining ExcelDNA with NetOffice.  Here is a snippet to get you started.  Note that you will need to cleanup your Application references to COM proxy objects in the OnDisconnection method.  For more details, check out [Excel Addin Portability Tutorial](http://tyrisias.blogspot.com/2016/12/excel-add-in-development-portability.html)

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ProgId("Sample.MyAddIn")]
public class MyRibbon : ExcelRibbon
{

   public override void OnConnection(object comApp, ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode, object objAddin, ref Array custom)
   {
     // glue NetOffice + Excel DNA
     m_ExcelApplication = new Application(null, m_ComApplication);
     // other initialization... 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically you get rid of the Com object issue and keep everything under the same namespace?